# Emulating socket event how do I update the relevant view with received model data?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am trying to emulate multiple socket responses listening for each response in my view and updating the model, right now however I am managing to update each view with the same data. Can anyone advise what I would need to have in place in order to update the view relating to the data, right now I'm very confused about how this all works like should there be unique data in the response, should I check this in the view or the model etc?

**Sample JS**

```
    function outputData(id, name) {
    return {
        id: id,
        name: name
    }
};

var View = Backbone.View.extend({

    className: 'view',

    template: Handlebars.compile( $('.tmpl-view').html() ),

    initialize: function() {
        this.listenTo(Backbone.Events, 'data:recieved', function(response) {
            // Check if this model data is related to this view then set?
            this.model.set(response);
            this.render();
        }.bind(this), this)
    },

    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
});

var viewOne = new View({
    model: new Backbone.Model()
});

var viewTwo = new View({
    model: new Backbone.Model()
});

$('body').append(
    viewOne.render().el,
    viewTwo.render().el
);

Backbone.Events.trigger('data:recieved', outputData(1, 'Data for viewOne'));

setTimeout(function() {
    Backbone.Events.trigger('data:recieved', outputData(2, 'Data for viewTwo'));
}, 400);
```

**JS Fiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/9kf9qvdg/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take a slightly different approach.  Your view should only listen to changes on the one model it is backed by.  This way each view doesn't need to parse every socket message:

```
initialize: function() {
    this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
}
```

Instead you would have separate logic that handles updating your models appropriately when you receive data. This might look like:

```
function updateData(id, msg) {
    var data = outputData(id, msg);
    var modelToUpdate = collection.findWhere({id: data.id});
    if(modelToUpdate) {
        modelToUpdate.set(data);
    }
}
```

Here is a fiddle showing the above in action: http://jsfiddle.net/xwmx64y3/

Comment: Is the updateData function something that could live inside the collection? Listen for the event inside the collection then run that method against the response?

Comment: Yes, absolutely -- you would just need to extend `Backbone.Collection` and specify the update function.  Ex: `var Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({updateData: function(data) { /* ... */ }});`

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot for helping me understand this. Was completely drawing a blank on the implementation!